# PHP Variables int and string, what to use correctly

Tags: php, operators, int

Can somebody explain advise me, why: (if I am setting DB field to int like "1" - this statement works, but if I am setting it as string - it doesn't work.

Works:

```
if ( $results['page']->pageStatus != 1 ) {
header('Location: 404.html');}
```

Doesn't work:

```
if ( $results['page']->pageStatus !== "active" ) {
header('Location: 404.html');}
```

Comment: try $results['page']->pageStatus != "active"

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($results['page']->pageStatus)`?

Comment: `!=` is a non-type strict comparison. You essentially wrote `if ( $results['page']->pageStatus)` with the first statement. Do a var_dump of `$results['page']->pageStatus`

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to see what it actually contains when your string comparison fails. We can't tell.

Comment: `!==` is a "not identical" comparison. See [PHP Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Thanks guys! All sorted now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

So when you do (and I strongly suspect that `$results['page']->pageStatus` is of type `string`):

```
if ( $results['page']->pageStatus != 1 )
```

`$results['page']->pageStatus` is converted to a number. In this case it is convert to `0`. And `0 != 1` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: Thanks guys! All sorted now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the expression to true or false. Change it to

`if ( !($results['page']->pageStatus == "active") ) {
header('Location: 404.html');}`

Comment: Does this when will be correct statment: if ( !($results['page']->pageStatus == "public" or "private") ) { header('Location: 404.html');}

Comment: you would need to use the or operator `||` and evaluate two expressions: `if ( !($results['page']->pageStatus == "public") || !($results['page']->pageStatus == "public")) { header('Location: 404.html');}` This says If page status is NOT equal to public or if pagestatus is NOT = private, then do stuff...

Comment: Thanks Benjiman, my problem was related to brackets "(" and ")". Now all works